# Import PMML file in MLlib

Tags: python, apache-spark-mllib, pmml

I have been given a PMML file containing a Naive Bayes classifier model.

Is it possible to import the PMML file into MLlib and reconstruct the model using Python programming language?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to import the PMML file into MLlib ..

No, it is not possible, because PMML and MLlib model representations are not compatible with one another.

If you have a PMML model, then you should execute it on Apache Spark using special-purpose PMML scoring library such as [JPMML-Spark](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-spark).

> .. and reconstruct the model using Python programming language?

Do you mean accessing PMML scoring functionality using PySpark? You can execute JPMML-Spark functions using PySpark, there is no need to reconstruct the model object inside Python for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PyPMML-Spark](https://github.com/autodeployai/pypmml-spark) to import PMML in PySpark, for example:

```
from pypmml_spark import ScoreModel

model = ScoreModel.fromFile('the/pmml/model/path')
score_df = model.transform(df)
```